# Redis | Terraform | Creates every time freshly after execution of terraform apply

Tags: redis, terraform

I am creating Redis in AWS using Terraform. But When I execute `terraform apply`  command for first time it creates without issues. But If I re-run `Terraform apply` below TF code destroys the Redis and starts re-creating it instead it should tell me that it already exists start focusing on other newly added resources .
Is it expected behaviour of Redis?

Adding terraform plan in the question:

```
-/+ resource "aws_elasticache_replication_group" "redis" {
        apply_immediately              = true
        at_rest_encryption_enabled     = true
        auto_minor_version_upgrade     = false
        automatic_failover_enabled     = true
      + configuration_endpoint_address = (known after apply)
        engine                         = "redis"
        engine_version                 = "5.0.4"
      ~ id                             = "dev-af-redis" -> (known after apply)
        maintenance_window             = "sun:06:00-sun:07:00"
      ~ member_clusters                = [
          - "ca-cng-dev-af-redis-001",
          - "ca-cng-dev-af-redis-002",
        ] -> (known after apply)
        node_type                      = "cache.t2.medium"
      ~ number_cache_clusters          = 2 -> (known after apply)
        parameter_group_name           = "default.redis5.0"
        port                           = 6379
      ~ primary_endpoint_address       = "master.dev-af-redis.qxyj8a.euc1.cache.amazonaws.com" -> (known after apply)
        replication_group_description  = "Airflow Cluster"
        replication_group_id           = "dev-af-redis"
        security_group_ids             = [
            "sg-094175ad3062da04d",
        ]
      ~ security_group_names           = [] -> (known after apply)
      - snapshot_retention_limit       = 0 -> null
      ~ snapshot_window                = "02:30-03:30" -> (known after apply)
        subnet_group_name              = "dev-subnet-group-airflow"
        tags                           = {
            "Application"    = "project"
            "BusinessUnit"   = "subproject"
            "Classification" = "private"
            "Environment"    = "development"
            "Name"           = "dev-airflow-redis"
            "TechnicalOwner" = "ops"
            "Tier"           = "orchestration"
        }
        transit_encryption_enabled     = true

      + cluster_mode {
          + num_node_groups         = 1
          + replicas_per_node_group = 1 # forces replacement
        }
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
```

TF code which used to create Redis:-

```
resource "aws_elasticache_replication_group" "cng_redis" {
  replication_group_description = "Cluster"
  replication_group_id          = "dev-af-redis"
  engine                        = "redis"
  engine_version                = "5.0.4"
  node_type                     = "cache.t2.medium "
  port                          = 6379
  subnet_group_name             = "dev-subnet-group-airflow"
  security_group_ids            = ["${aws_security_group.airflow_sg.id}"]
  parameter_group_name          = "default.redis5.0"
  at_rest_encryption_enabled    = true
  transit_encryption_enabled    = true
  maintenance_window            = "sun:06:00-sun:07:00"
  auto_minor_version_upgrade    = false
  apply_immediately             = true

  automatic_failover_enabled = true

  cluster_mode {
    num_node_groups         = "1"
    replicas_per_node_group = "1"
  }

  tags = merge(
    var.common_tags,
    map("Classification", "private"),
    map("Name", "airflow-redis")
  )
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the plan output where it wants to recreate things?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Added terraform plan in my question

Comment: Is that the initial plan, or the plan for the destroy/recreate?  I'd have expected to see a `-/+` for a destroy/recreate?

Comment: The plan also mentions the fact it's in a module - perhaps something else is changing higher up that's forcing this to happen?

Comment: @JamesThorpe Its not initial plan- The output is for recreate.

Comment: Any chance you can rework your question so that it's a [mcve] instead please? Right now there's not enough information for people to help you debug this.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I have edited my question. Please suggest accordingly.

Comment: @JamesThorpe I have edited my question. Please suggest accordingly.

Comment: You now no longer have any code in the question at all. It might be worth reading the [mcve] link in my comment and seeing what you should produce. Right now all we can see is that for you Terraform wants to create a Redis cluster from scratch and doesn't have any knowledge of the existing Redis cluster but we have no idea how to get in that same state.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Apologies for the confusion. I have updated my question as per your suggestion.

Comment: That plan is very different to what you showed before. It looks like it's just that you're going from using `number_cache_clusters` in an cluster mode disabled replication group to using a cluster mode enabled replication group. This is expected to cause a rebuild as you can't modify an existing replication group this way.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Could you suggest me what I need to overcome this?

Comment: Overcome what? You're changing something that can't be changed so Terraform wants to destroy and recreate. You need to either make the change and allow for that, including working out the issue with the downtime/data loss incurred by that, or not make the change.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR Could you tell what exactly is the change I need to do in my code to avoid recreating Redis again?

Comment: Don't add the cluster config. The plan is saying you originally defined `number_cache_clusters` but now you're adding a `cluster_mode` block instead. This is a breaking change. Either revert the change or accept the recreation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution ("this is not a bug, it's a feature" case, I suppose ;) ): https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/4817#issuecomment-463993424

I tested it and it works.
You have to add parameter group with `cluster-enabled` set to yes.
I'm using Redis 5.0.5, so to my `aws_elasticache_replication_group` I added:

```
resource "aws_elasticache_replication_group" "elc-rep-group" {
  ...
  automatic_failover_enabled = true #this is required, when cluster-enabled parameter is on
  parameter_group_name = "default.redis5.0.cluster.on"
  ...
}
```